# Make method work with activerecord grouped objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a bunch of objects, and I grouped them by the day they happened.

```
scope :grouped_by_user_with_total_time, lambda {
  group(:user_id, :day).select('user_id, SUM(time_worked) AS time_total, day, editable, approvable, accepted, comments')
}
```

I also have some methods that change editable, approvable, and accepted. But now since they are grouped, I get this error when trying to approve grouped objects.

> Couldn't find TimeLog without an ID

My `approve` method:

```
def approve
  @time_logs = []
  t = TimeLog.find(params[:time_logs])

  if t.instance_of?(Array)
    @time_logs = t
  else
    @time_logs << t
  end
end
```

What do I have to change so that the methods can work on all of the hourlogs that are grouped together?

```
    <% @time_logss.each do |timelog| %>
      <% if timelog.user_id != current_user.id %>
      <tr>
        <!--<td><%# check_box_tag 'accept' %></td>-->
        <td><%= timelog.id_name %></td>
        <td><%= timelog.day.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></td>
        <td><%= timelog.time_total %></td>
        <td><%= timelog.state %></td>
            <% if timelog.state == "Submitted" %>
        <td><%= link_to "Approve", approve_time_sheets_path(time_sheets: timelog), method: :put %></td>
```

Comment: In rails , method "find" accepts an id or an array of id, so what's your params[:time_logs] ? It can't be null.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is sending when i try to execute the method, it only shows me that

Comment: Could you please post your relative view codes and backtraces?

Comment: I added the view code

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine an aggregate function with the need to access unique data.  When you use .select(''), you are telling AR which fields to populate into the object (even attributes that do not exist directly in the database).

If you add in time_logs.*, you'll lose the aggregate on time_worked, since you'll then be forced to add id to the group clause.

What you need to do have 1 instance var with the time_logs and one with the aggregate data:

```
@time_logs = TimeLog.all
@time_totals = TimeLog.grouped_by_user_with_total_time
```

Then, in the view, you can pluck out the correct total for each time_log.  Although, I'm not clear on how you will be able to relate the specific time_log with it's aggregate equivalent.